# What scripting language is this?

Tags: scripting, scripting-language

I am trying to edit the outputs for a program called SpaceSniffer but I'm not sure what the scripting language is.

```
{script}
{   if {<%isfile%>} == {true}
  ? {  [{leftpad{<%disksize%>}{ }{8}}] <%file%>{&br}}
  : {   if {<%containsfiles%>} == {true}
      ? {{&br}<%pathfile%> [<%disksize%>]{&br}}
    }
}
```

That is one of the scripts that is provided with the program for the output, I have tried asking the creator of this software but apparently he replies after within a day so if anyone knows of this scripting language that would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the extension you found this script in? E.g.: `.php`, `.html`, `.exe`

Comment: Sorry there are no extensions maybe I used the wrong word for that. I am trying to edit the output, but as I don't know what language it is I'm kind of struggling with it.

Comment: Oh now I get what you mean, the script is internal in the program and then they are saved in a config file. There doesn't seem to be a way to directly export only the script to see the extension.

Comment: Maybe the creator of the program created his own language, since I can't recognize what language this is.

Comment: I would guess that it is a custom language. It is documented in the User Manual. Isn't that all you need?

Comment: Yes it is documented but I cant find what I need in there. Was hoping that it was a know scripting language so I could search online, never mind thanks for the comments anyway I'll have to figure something out.